# Ada compilation warnings

Tags: ada

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use  Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure factorial_ada is

    n, i : Integer;
    output : Integer := 1;

begin
    Put_Line("Enter the number to be taken factorial of: ");
    Get(n);

   -- Begin Loop
    for i in 2..n
    loop
        output := output * i;
    end loop;

    Put("Factorial of "); 
    Put(n); 
    Put(" is "); 
    Put(output);

end factorial_ada;
```

My code compiles and works but I"m getting a warning which says
"variable "i" is never read and never assigned" 
"for loop implicitly declares loop variable"
"declaration hides "i" declared at line 15"

How do I fix this?

Comment: nvm my variable "i" was never used.

Comment: Because if you expected a specific value in your "i" variable after the loop, you might get a surprise. Ada is not meant to be about that sort of surprise. so the compiler was trying to be helpful.

Comment: One way to "fix" this is to turn off warnings. Note that line 15 in your code is `loop`, not a declaration, so the messages you've given are not for the code that you've given. In this case it's obvious what is meant, but in more complex questions it's a good idea to make sure that any compiler messages given are generated by the code presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I compile your code with `-gnatl` (listing of source with error messages in line), it gives

```
 1. with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
 2. use  Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
 3.
 4. procedure factorial_ada is
 5.
 6.     n, i : Integer;
           |
    >>> warning: variable "i" is never read and never assigned

 7.     output : Integer := 1;
 8.
 9. begin
10.     Put_Line("Enter the number to be taken factorial of: ");
11.     Get(n);
12.
13.    -- Begin Loop
14.     for i in 2..n
            |
    >>> warning: for loop implicitly declares loop variable
    >>> warning: declaration hides "i" declared at line 6

15.     loop
16.         output := output * i;
17.     end loop;
18.
19.     Put("Factorial of ");
20.     Put(n);
21.     Put(" is ");
22.     Put(output);
23.
24. end factorial_ada;
```

The warnings at line 14 remind you that ([ARM 5.5(11)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-5-5.html#p11))

> An object_declaration should not be given for a loop parameter, since the loop parameter is automatically declared by the loop_parameter_specification. The scope of a loop parameter extends from the loop_parameter_specification to the end of the loop_statement, and the visibility rules are such that a loop parameter is only visible within the sequence_of_statements of the loop.

The warning at line 6 is telling you that this `i` (an "object declaration", in ARM-speak) has nothing to do with the `i` at line 14.

This is similar to the C++ rules: writing

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i;
  int output = 1;
  int n = 12;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    output *= i;
  }
  printf("factorial %d is %d\n", i, output);
  return 0;
}
```

results in

```
$ g++ hk.cc -Wall
hk.cc: In function 'int main()':
hk.cc:9:9: warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    9 |   printf("factorial %d is %d\n", i, output);
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```